# Modify the sidebar of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uisearchbar

my `UITableView` has a bunch of sections and therefore displays a sidebar, which let's you scroll through the sections.

The problem is: I have a `UISearchBar` in the header of the `UITableView`, and the sidebar covers the clear (x) button of the `UISearchBar`.

Can I modify the sidebar to add margin or at least remove it completely? I couldn't find anything on the sidebar on the Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this view made in a xib file is the question?? If you do you should be able to resize the table view to do however big you want it.  Here is a link on the apple developer site that has a lot of helpful information about UITableViews and UITableCells:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0):

The UISearchBar is the headerView of the TableView. I want the strange stuff on the side moved down by the height of the SearchBar, or completely removed.

I figured out, that you can remove the bar with

`self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = 1337;`

At least, if you have less than 1337 sections. However, if anyone knows how I access the object which represents the index on the right directly to resize it and move it down, please let me know.

Image of the cause: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/5397/bildschirmfoto20101121us.png

I think it's a bug in UITableView, so I'm going to report it to Apple.

Comment: You can set self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount to NSIntegerMax instead of an arbitrary large number. Also, you would have to call [self.tableView reloadData] if you set this after the table data is loaded.